# Writing test to check functionality

Tags: apex, unit-test

Test Class

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true) static void test_method_one() {
        // Implement test code

        List<Account> lstAcc; 
        Map<Id, Account> oldMap;  
        Id MyId; 
        Account myAcc;
        Account oldAcc;
        List<Account> myList;
        //MCG obj;// = new MCG(); 

        // Implement test code
        Test.startTest();

        /*List<RecordType> lst = [SELECT Id from RecordType where DeveloperName = 'X0_Si_ge_Centrale' and sObjecttype = 'Account' Limit 1];
        Integer rtID_Acc;
        if(!lst.isEmpty()){
            rtID_Acc = lst[0].Id;
        }*/

        lstAcc = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account where
                    RecordTypeId = '012D00000002qdE' and R_seau_int_gr__c = true and Etat_relation_GEO__c = 'Déploiement' LIMIT 1]; 

        if(lstAcc.size()>0) {
            System.debug('test_lstAccountEvents : simulation trigger ');
            myList = lstAcc;
            MyId = lstAcc[0].Id; 
            System.debug('New trigger '+lstAcc.get(0).Etat_relation_geo__c);
            //lstAcc.get(0).Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Déploiement';
            oldAcc = lstAcc[0];
            oldAcc.Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';

            oldMap = new Map<Id, Account>{
                MyId=> oldAcc
            }; 
            //oldMap.get(MyId).Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';

            LogAccountEvents.lstLogAccountEvents(myList, oldMap);           
            System.assert(true);

            Boolean hasHierarchy = true;
            List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

           List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();
           accIds.add(MyId);
}
}
```

Apex Code:

```
public static void lstLogAccountEvents(List<Account> lstNewAccs, Map<Id,Account> oldMapAccs){

        LogAccountTasks__c lgtAcc;
        List<LogAccountTasks__c> lstLogAccounttaks = new List<LogAccountTasks__c>();
        List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();
        Boolean hasHierarchy;
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        Id rtID_Acc  = null;

        List<RecordType> lstRTIDAcc = [SELECT Id from RecordType where DeveloperName = 'X0_Si_ge_Centrale' and sObjecttype = 'Account' Limit 1];

        if(!lstRTIDAcc.isEmpty()){
            rtID_Acc = lstRTIDAcc[0].Id;
        }

        //Déploiment Statut
        //if(lstNewAccs != null && oldMapAccs != null){
            for (Account a : lstNewAccs){
                if(!lstNewAccs.isEmpty())
                System.debug('statut déploiment');

                System.debug('reseau integre ' + a.R_seau_int_gr__c);
                System.debug('etat relation ' + a.Etat_relation_GEO__c);
                System.debug('old map ' + oldMapAccs.get(a.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c);
                System.debug('Account Record type ID' + a.RecordTypeId);
                System.debug('Record Type Id ' + rtID_Acc);

                System.debug('Id in Déploiment' + a.Id);

                if (a.RecordTypeId == rtID_Acc && a.R_seau_int_gr__c == true && a.Etat_relation_GEO__c == 'Déploiement' && (oldMapAccs == null 
                    || oldMapAccs.get(a.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c != 'Déploiement'))
                    {
                        System.debug('Statut Déploiment');
                        hasHierarchy = true;
                        System.debug('Id in Déploiment' + a.Id);
                        accIds.add(a.id);
                        while (hasHierarchy)
                        {
                            List<Account> pareAccs = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account WHERE (Etat_relation_GEO__c != 'Terminé' AND parentId IN :accIds)];
                            accIds.clear();
                            if (pareAccs == null || pareAccs.isEmpty()){
                                System.debug('Size ' +pareAccs.size());
                                hasHierarchy = false;
                             }
                            for (Account ac : pareAccs)
                            {
                                System.debug('parents exist en statut different de Terminé');
                                accIds.add(ac.id);
                                accountsToUpdate.add(ac);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
       // }

        accIds.clear();

        //Terminé statut
            for (Account acc : lstNewAccs){

                if(!lstNewAccs.isEmpty())
                System.debug('statut terminé');
                System.debug('List is not empty');
                System.debug('developer name ' + acc.RecordType.DeveloperName);
                System.debug('reseau integre ' + acc.R_seau_int_gr__c);
                System.debug('etat relation ' + acc.Etat_relation_GEO__c);
                System.debug('old map ' + oldMapAccs.get(acc.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c);
                System.debug('developer name ' + RecordType.DeveloperName);

                System.debug('Id ' + acc.Id);

                if (acc.RecordTypeId == rtID_Acc && acc.R_seau_int_gr__c == true && acc.Etat_relation_GEO__c == 'Terminé' && (oldMapAccs == null 
                    || oldMapAccs.get(acc.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c != 'Terminé'))
                    {
                        System.debug('Statut Terminé');
                        hasHierarchy = true;
                        System.debug('Id ' + acc.Id);
                        accIds.add(acc.id);
                        while (hasHierarchy)
                        {
                            List<Account> parentAccs = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account WHERE parentId IN :accIds];
                            accIds.clear();
                            if (parentAccs == null || parentAccs.isEmpty()){
                                System.debug('Size ' +parentAccs.size());
                                hasHierarchy = false;
                            }
                            for (Account aa : parentAccs)
                            {
                                System.debug('parents exist en statut different de Déploiement');
                                accIds.add(aa.id);
                                accountsToUpdate.add(aa);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

        if(accountsToUpdate!=null && !accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            for(Account acc : accountsToUpdate){
                lgtAcc = new LogAccountTasks__c();
                lgtAcc.AccountId__c = acc.Id;
                lgtAcc.AccRTDeveloperName__c = acc.RecordType.DeveloperName;
                lgtAcc.AccRecordTypeId__c = acc.RecordTypeId;
                System.debug('old id ' + oldMapAccs.get(acc.Id));
                lgtAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c = acc.Etat_relation_geo__c; //NewTrigger 
                if(lgtAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c == 'Déploiement')
                    lgtAcc.Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé'; //oldMap
                else if (lgtAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c == 'Terminé') {
                    lgtAcc.Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Déploiement';
                }
                lgtAcc.Type_de_reseau__c = acc.R_seau_int_gr__c;
                lgtAcc.Flag__c = false;
                lgtAcc.CreationDate__c =  DateTime.now();
                System.debug('Account id ' + acc.Id);
                //System.debug('Unique id ' + lgtAcc.UniqueId__c);
                lstLogAccounttaks.add(lgtAcc);
            }

        insert lstLogAccounttaks;
        }
}
}
```

And My test is not covering following functionality:

```
                        || oldMapAccs.get(a.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c != 'Déploiement'))
                        {
                            System.debug('Statut Déploiment');
                            hasHierarchy = true;
                            System.debug('Id in Déploiment' + a.Id);
                            accIds.add(a.id);
                            while (hasHierarchy)
                            {
                                List<Account> pareAccs = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account WHERE (Etat_relation_GEO__c != 'Terminé' AND parentId IN :accIds)];
                                accIds.clear();
                                if (pareAccs == null || pareAccs.isEmpty()){
                                     System.debug('Size ' +pareAccs.size());
                                    hasHierarchy = false;
                                 }
                                for (Account ac : pareAccs)
                                {
                                    System.debug('parents exist en statut different de Terminé');
                                    accIds.add(ac.id);
                                    accountsToUpdate.add(ac);

               hasHierarchy = true;
                            System.debug('Id ' + acc.Id);
                            accIds.add(acc.id);
                            while (hasHierarchy)
                            {
                                List<Account> parentAccs = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account WHERE parentId IN :accIds];
                                accIds.clear();
                                if (parentAccs == null || parentAccs.isEmpty()){
                                    System.debug('Size ' +parentAccs.size());
                                    hasHierarchy = false;
                                }
                                for (Account aa : parentAccs)
                                {
                                    System.debug('parents exist en statut different de Déploiement');
                                    accIds.add(aa.id);
                                    accountsToUpdate.add(aa);


 for(Account acc : accountsToUpdate){
                    lgtAcc = new LogAccountTasks__c();
                    lgtAcc.AccountId__c = acc.Id;
                    lgtAcc.AccRTDeveloperName__c = acc.RecordType.DeveloperName;
                    lgtAcc.AccRecordTypeId__c = acc.RecordTypeId;
                    System.debug('old id ' + oldMapAccs.get(acc.Id));
                    lgtAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c = acc.Etat_relation_geo__c; //NewTrigger 
                    if(lgtAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c == 'Déploiement')
                        lgtAcc.Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé'; //oldMap
                    else if (lgtAcc.Etat_futur_de_la_relation_geo__c == 'Terminé') {
                        lgtAcc.Etat_actuel_de_la_relation_geo__c = 'Déploiement';
                    }
                    lgtAcc.Type_de_reseau__c = acc.R_seau_int_gr__c;
                    lgtAcc.Flag__c = false;
                    lgtAcc.CreationDate__c =  DateTime.now();
                    System.debug('Account id ' + acc.Id);
                    //System.debug('Unique id ' + lgtAcc.UniqueId__c);
                    lstLogAccounttaks.add(lgtAcc);
                }

            insert lstLogAccounttaks;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce only marks code as "covered" if that code is executed as part of at least one unit test.

The two blocks of code that you indicate as not covered are part of two separate `if()` blocks.

```
if (a.RecordTypeId == rtID_Acc && a.R_seau_int_gr__c == true && a.Etat_relation_GEO__c == 'Déploiement' && (oldMapAccs == null 
                || oldMapAccs.get(a.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c != 'Déploiement'))
```

and

```
if (acc.RecordTypeId == rtID_Acc && acc.R_seau_int_gr__c == true && acc.Etat_relation_GEO__c == 'Terminé' && (oldMapAccs == null 
                || oldMapAccs.get(acc.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c != 'Terminé'))`
```

Looking at the Apex code you're trying to test, it seems like you're passing in collections of SObjects. That's good, and generally makes testing a bit easier. Let's take a look to see if you're providing the right data as part of your test...

```
lstAcc = [SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Etat_relation_geo__c, R_seau_int_gr__c FROM Account where
                RecordTypeId = '012D00000002qdE' and R_seau_int_gr__c = true and Etat_relation_GEO__c = 'Déploiement' LIMIT 1]; 

if(lstAcc.size()>0) {
    System.debug('test_lstAccountEvents : simulation trigger ');
    myList = lstAcc;
    MyId = lstAcc[0].Id; 
    System.debug('New trigger '+lstAcc.get(0).Etat_relation_geo__c);
    //lstAcc.get(0).Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Déploiement';
    oldAcc = lstAcc[0];
    oldAcc.Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';

    oldMap = new Map<Id, Account>{
        MyId=> oldAcc
    }; 
    //oldMap.get(MyId).Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';

    LogAccountEvents.lstLogAccountEvents(myList, oldMap);
```

Assuming that the record type Id for recordType `X0_Si_ge_Centrale` is indeed `012D00000002qdE`, your query ensures that any returned record will have `R_seau_int_gr__c == true` and `Etat_relation_GEO__c == 'Déploiement'`

Given your test code, I can say that this one test can *only possibly satisfy one of the two `if()` statements that you're trying to gain coverage for*. That, by itself, is fine. It has some implications that I will get into a bit later.

The reason why your unit test isn't covering *either* of your two `if()` blocks comes down to a couple of lines in your test class

```
// When assigning a variable from data contained in a collection (map, set, or list),
//   the variable will contain a _reference_ to the data stored in that collection.
oldAcc = lstAcc[0];

// When you make a change to a reference, the original instance is changed as well.
// If you system.debug(listAcc[0].Etat_relation_geo__c); after this statement, it
//   will show 'Terminé' instead of 'Déploiement'
oldAcc.Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';

// Adding data to a map also stores a reference
oldMap = new Map<Id, Account>{
    MyId=> oldAcc
};
```

So when you get to your `if()` statements in the code you're trying to test...

- `a.Etat_relation_GEO__c` is 'Terminé'
- `oldMapAccs.get(a.Id).Etat_relation_GEO__c` is also 'Terminé'

This satisfies *neither* of your two `if()` statements, therefore, the given unit test does not execute the code inside the `if()` blocks, and you don't gain coverage. Since those two `if()` blocks are never executed, `accountsToUpdate()` never has anything added to it, which explains why your `for()` loop isn't being executed/covered either.

To do what you intend, you need to make a slight change to your setup code.

```
// Instead of directly assigning listAcc[0] (which would give you a reference to
//   the Account stored in the list), you want to _clone_ it.
// Specifying all 4 parameters to clone() as true is important here
oldAcc = lstAcc[0].clone(true, true, true, true);

// Clone() makes a completely separate instance of the object in memory.
// That means that changes you make to one will not affect the other
oldAcc.Etat_relation_geo__c = 'Terminé';

// Adding data to a map also stores a reference, but since they're references
//   to two separate locations in memory, it's fine
oldMap = new Map<Id, Account>{
    MyId=> oldAcc
};
```

Doing that should give you coverage for your second `if()` block.

That said, there are other issues with your unit test that should be fixed.

- Using `@isTest(seeAllData=true)` is not good practice. It breaks test isolation, which is one of the useful aspects of unit tests (the isolation, in theory, allows you to run tests simultaneously). Test isolation also ensures that changes your test makes to data does not persist past the execution of the test. *Creating your test data, and all of its dependencies, as part of a unit test is the recommended practice for unit testing*.
- Hard-coding Ids is also poor practice. Tests with hard-coded Ids have a tendency to break when run from different orgs (between sandboxes, or even between a sandbox and production). For `Recordtype` ids, you can use `Schema.SOBjectType.<sobject name>.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(<record type name>).getRecordTypeId();` instead.
- Don't attempt to have one unit test that tests everything. If you have logic that executes under different conditions (like the two separate `if()` blocks you're trying to gain coverage for), *write one unit test per condition*. Doing this can simplify the test setup you need to do, and makes it significantly easier to figure out what is broken when your test(s) fail.
- The main purpose of unit tests is not to gain code coverage, but rather to ensure that your code behaves the way you expect it to. For that, you need to make assertions. In your case, after you return from `LogAccountEvents.lstLogAccountEvents(myList, oldMap);`, you'd want to query for the child `Accounts` under the `Accounts` you passed into the method you were testing, then query for `LogAccountTasks__c` records related to them, and assert that there were `LogAccounTasks__c` records created (and also that the field values match your expectations).

Comment: Thanks a lot Derek. It was very helpful I was struggling for this code. Thanks alot Again.